# Definition of "with dense range"

Tags: definition

it is written "T is a continuous map **with dense range**". What is the definition of map with dense range? Maybe it's simple but I am not native English speaker, thanks.

Comment: I think it means that the range is a dense subset. For example, if you have a vector space $V$, a function $T$ has a dense range if $T\langle V \rangle$ is dense, i.e. it's closure is $V$.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is a continuous map from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$,
then $T$  is said to have a dense range if the set $T(X)$ is a dense subset of $Y$. That is, every non-empty open set in $Y$ has a non-empty intersection with $T(X)$.

Comment: Thank you very much :D